# Connecting to VPC-based Kibana using AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, kibana, amazon-cognito, aws-elasticsearch

I'm a beginner to AWS and a bit confused regarding the AWS Cognito system.

I have an AWS Elasticsearch service behind a VPC. I'm trying to access the Kibana endpoint using AWS Cognito, but when I navigate to the log in screen I see a blank page.

Is what I'm trying to do feasible or do I need to VPN first into the VPC in order to get to the log in screen? If so, how can I grant public users access to Kibana (without the trouble of a VPN?) Would a better solution be to have a reverse proxy point to Kibana and couple this with AWS Cognito? Thanks for your help.

Note: I'm using Elasticsearch 6.2

Answer (score 0):

I had the same output while I was setting up the same setup but don't remember exactly which stage solved it.

At this stage it looks like you already set your access policy to use the Cognito role otherwise you wouldn't end up on the cognito login page (even though blank for now).

I would check the identity provider config on the Cognito User Pool App client settings:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-cognito-auth.html#es-cognito-auth-identity-providers

It wasn't linked to a lack of access (ie. no VPN) or a missing UI customization and it's definitely achievable.
Let me know if you want me to look deeper into it.

EDIT: when i go directly to the domain url of my cognito pool (ie. https://yourdomain.auth.your-region.amazoncognito.com) I still get a blank page. It's only when going to the protected application (kibana) that the login page is filled in (probably linked to the above app client settings).

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for your comment! I ended up using a public endpoint Elasticsearch (which worked fine). I'm not sure if I understand you correctly: When you navigate to https://vpc-domain-name-identifier.region.es.amazonaws.com/_plugin/kibana you end up on the log in screen and you are able to access Kibana without the use of a VPN or any kind of SSH tunnelling? I'm still skeptical whether AWS Cognito can work with a VPC-based ES - but curious. I had a similar discussion on this Medium post (see comments below) https://medium.com/tensult/aws-cognito-authentication-for-kibana-7f1f99dacb5

Comment: We do have site to site VPN between the on-prem network and the VPC.
The VPC is to have things "internally" accessible. Usually you don't build a VPC solely for kibana so you probably have a VPN of some sort if you want to leverage other VPC functionalities (ie. EC2).
I confirm that VPC ES + Cognito works fine, my current setup is VPC based ES + Cognito that relies on an external provider (SAML). I can manage access authorization and authentication to the Kibana exactly like any other application within my IDP system. 
Downside, VPC flow logs can't be pushed to VPC based ES via Firehose.

Answer (score 0):

I created a wiki page in my GitHub Repo because I did this EXACT (Public ESS and Cognito) same thing over the last couple days. You can get the info [HERE](https://github.com/Talderon/AWS_CloudFormation/wiki/AWS-ElasticSearch-Service-Plus-Cognito---How-To-Put-It-All-Together) and I hope it helps clear things up!